# What is the minimum size conduit/mast required for a 100 amp overhead service?

Tags: electrical

What is the minimum size conduit/mast required for a 100 amp single phase 240 volt overhead electrical service?

Answer (score 1):

Although you're probably safe by using the NEC as a minimum, this is going to vary somewhat based on jurisdiction and power company. You should contact your local inspection authority and your power company.

Answer (score 1):

Service mast size will be specified by the local utility, though 2" rigid metal conduit is common. National Electrical Code (NEC) only has this to say...

> ## National Electrical Code 2011
>
> ### Article 230 Services
>
> #### Overhead Service-Drop Conductors
>
> **230.28 Service Masts as Supports.** Where a service mast is used for the support of service-drop conductors, it shall be of adequate strength or be supported by braces or guys to withstand safely the strain imposed by the service drop. Where raceway-type service masts are used, all raceway fittings shall be identified for use with service masts. Only power service-drop conductors shall be permitted to be attached to a service mast.

The local utility will not connect service conductors to a service point that does not meet their standards, so only they can tell you what they expect.